# parameter of div which is hidden by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are two tabs in my page, I wanted to confirm whether the parameter of hidden tab will be submitted. Is there some one who knows that?

```
$("somePart").hide();
```

Comment: What do you mean by parameter? Please add more details.

Comment: Do you mean, will form fields submit if they are hidden?  If so, the answer is yes, but why not just try it yourself and see what happens?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean some attribute from the element (div) then yes, you can get that using:

```
$('div').click(function () {
 $(this).attr('id');
}
```

This above code will give you the ID of the div. You can get other attributes similarly. I guess you mean these by the parameters.

If you want to know that will the div with the `display: none` will be submitted, then sure thing! In a form each and every input is sent to the server, there is a hidden input too.

By default, everything is sent to server from the `form`. So you will get the hidden fields as well as the visible ones.

You can use `input[type="hidden"]` to check which of the tab is being submitted. So that youc an differentiate how these two tabs are submitted.

Answer (score 0):

The jquery api says that the 'hide' method is the the same as adding `display: hidden` to the css. http://api.jquery.com/hide/

In order to find out if the element is hidden, you can use

```
$("somePart").css("display");
```

if the value returned is hidden, the element is hidden. If not, the element is visible.